# Html tags in Django admin text editors

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

I just put up a Django CMS [here](http://www.nigelrahkola.com/) and I've run into a problem when trying to post content. I can only post raw text without any html tags.

I want the functionality of the flatpages app where I can tag my own paragraphs, headers, etc.

Is my solution as simple as changing a setting/modifying my templates, or do I have to look into adding a text editor like Dojo?

The code for my Django CMS: https://github.com/Jollyra/blog

Comment: Try {{ flatpage.content|safe }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also might find the following useful for your website. You can use markdown, Textile or reST. Instructions for setting this up are on the link below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/markup/.

As was said above, you need to mark the content as safe otherwise the template will escape the output to avoid HTML or Javascript injection and for convenience. You can mark the output of tags as safe in the Django template language as follows:

```
{{ tag|safe }}
```

Or in the case of flatpages:

```
{{ flatpage.content|safe }}
```